# Magento version upgrade issue - Integrity constraint violation - mysql4-install-1.4.0.8.php

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.7, magento

I receive the following error when I tried to upgrade my Magento version from 1.4 to 1.7.
Please help

**Error in file:** "/home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/sql/xmlconnect_setup/mysql4-install-1.4.0.8.php" - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3-thumbnail' for key 'entity_type_id'

```
Trace:
0 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(390):
Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')                                                                                    

/home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(276):
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.0')
2 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(240):
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.0')
3 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(161):
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
4 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(363):
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
5 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(295): 
Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
6 /home/public_html/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
7 /home/public_html/index.php(82): Mage::run('', 'store')
  8 {main}
```

Comment: Any idea guys, please let me know?